# Show First 10 Highest/Lower value in my Line Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to deepen this code, and show me the top 10 highest values, and the 10 lowest values. do you think it would be possible following the example given to me?

```
  Dim myList = TxtNumberListCount.Lines.ToList
        Dim removedEmptyLinesCount = myList.RemoveAll(Function(str) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        Dim minValue = myList.Select(Function(line)
                                         Dim res = 0
                                         Integer.TryParse(line, res)
                                         Return res
                                     End Function).Min() ' or Max()
        Dim lineIndex = myList.IndexOf(minValue) + removedEmptyLinesCount
        TxtBoxMinValue1.Text = minValue
        TxtBoxCountMinValue1.Text = lineIndex
        Dim myList1 = TxtNumberListCount.Lines.ToList
        Dim removedEmptyLinesCount1 = myList1.RemoveAll(Function(str) String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
        Dim maxValue = myList1.Select(Function(line)
                                          Dim res = 0
                                          Integer.TryParse(line, res)
                                          Return res
                                      End Function).Max() ' or Max()
        Dim lineIndex1 = myList1.IndexOf(maxValue) + removedEmptyLinesCount
        TxtBoxMaxValue1.Text = maxValue
        TxtBoxCountMaxValue1.Text = lineIndex1
        TextBox6.Text = TxtNumberListScan.Lines(TxtBoxCountMinValue1.Text)
        TextBox7.Text = TxtNumberListScan.Lines(TxtBoxCountMaxValue1.Text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the most 10 highest values:

```
Dim Top10HighestValues = myList.Select(Function(line)
                                          Dim res = 0
                                          Integer.TryParse(line, res)
                                          Return res
                                        End Function).OrderByDescending(Function(x) x).Take(10)
```

And to get the most 10 lowest values you need to replace `OrderByDescending` with `OrderBy`:

```
Dim Top10LowestValues = myList.Select(Function(line)
                                          Dim res = 0
                                          Integer.TryParse(line, res)
                                          Return res
                                        End Function).OrderBy(Function(x) x).Take(10)
```

Save values and indexes into a Dictionary:

```
  Dim dictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
  For Each i In Top10HighestValues 
       Dim idx = myList.IndexOf(i) + removedEmptyLinesCount
       dictionary.Add(i, idx)
  Next



 For Each d In Dictionary
        TextBox2.AppendText(d.Key & vbCrLf)
        TextBox2.AppendText(d.Value & vbCrLf)
 Next
```

**Edit** to get the indexes

Comment: How do i do count Lines? find Lines, for all values. (LineIndex)

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Not Indexes, and on which line each value is. the previous code was better.

Comment: you had to keep the previous code, I see you deleted it.

Comment: `For Each i In Top10HighestValues 
      TextBox2.AppendText(i & vbCrLf)
Next`

Comment: Okay. Good. What I really want is to show the corresponding line on which the 10 Highest, and Lower. from TxtNumberListCount.

Comment: I am trying to understand, you mean the line number right?

Comment: Yes. that's what I want, to display the lines on which the values in the Top 10 (ie number and line)

Comment: And that's exactly what my last update do,
`Dim idx = myList.IndexOf(i) + removedEmptyLinesCount`

Comment: how do I send the top 10 - tophighest, toplower in my textbox1 and textbox2, and corresponding line? that's what I'm trying, but I can not work.

Comment: You need to read about [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2)

anyways I updated the code

Comment: Now worked, but I do not understand why I only show them for value 8, not 10. I finally managed to get him to go, I replaced 10 by 12, and now he is showing me the 10 values + the line. thank you.